# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) database connection to NodeJS

Tags: node.js, database, ssms

There are samples out there how to connect SSMS database to NodeJS.
However they show it using your own credentials like example on this link:https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/access-sql-server-in-nodejs

Question is, how to connect it without using own credentials? Directly may be with window authentication instead?
So that your application (NodeJS) connected with SSMS database without your own credential being saved in the server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're always going to need credentials to connect to the server. You can use things like [https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv](.env files) so that the credentials are not stored directly in your application.

Comment: SSMS isn't a database, it's an IDE. SQL Server is what hosts the data, SSMS is just an application you can use to interact with it.

Comment: thanks for clarification on the terminology here. Looking for sample/documentation on how to connect SQL Server to NodeJS without user credential - instead using windows authentication mode. Any tips or ideas appreciated.